C# How to flexibly represent mixed intermediate scalar/vector results in DSL expression evaluator
I want to evaluate expressions like:
LARGEST(A) + B

        A is double[] {1,2,3,4,5}
        B is double[] {2,3,4,5,6}

I'm using Irony and can create a suitable abstract syntax tree:
1. binary_add
2.     function_largest
3.         var_A
4.     var_B

The question is what sort of class or variable is flexible enough to house different types of intermediate results in the calculation process?

The intermediate results can be either scalar or vector (i.e. double versus double[]) and can't be known until evaluation time.

The code needs to figure out which Add overload to use at runtime based on the previous intermediate result:


void Add(double[] vector, double scalar) {}
void Add(double scalar1, double scalar2) {}
void Add(double[] vector1, double[] vector2) {}

                            evaluation order
binary_add                  4. {7,8,9,10,11}     vector (calculated element-wise addition of largest()'s scalar result to each vector entry)
    function_largest        2. 5                 scalar (calculated)
        var_A               1. {1,2,3,4,5}       vector (given)
    var_B                   3. {2,3,4,5,6}       vector (given)

Last resort I can just use object and do a lot of .GetType() in an if-statement to pick a suitable overload, but is there a smarter or more idiomatic way that I'm not thinking of? (Dynamics? Generics? etc.)

Do you care about strong/strict-typing - or not? I note that nothing is stopping you from defining your own union-types for use in your expression-language.

I care about strict typing in the sense that I want to use System.Numerics.Vector to do the math part because I benchmarked it as being much faster than Parallel.For where this is going to run (my actual vectors will have 400 to 1200 elements.) I don't have firsthand experience with unions in C#.
